# How to keep IntelliSense Complete Word option off?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

IntelliSense has a mode where if you hit the spacebar, it will automatically type out the suggested auto-complete word. In order to prevent this from happening, you can hit the Escape key before pressing Space. This will close the autocomplete popup, so that the suggested word is not automatically typed.

I prefer the alternative setting, where I actually have to hit the Enter key to accept the suggested autocompletion. If I just type Space, I want a space to follow the characters that I actually typed.

I know that I can toggle between the undesired mode and the second mode I describe, which I do want. To do this, I click Edit -> IntelliSence -> Toggle Completion Mode.

My problem is that this setting never sticks. It constantly reverts to the wrong mode. I'm not sure exactly when it's changing, but it seems to revert back several times a day. If I change this for one Solution, it won't apply to my other Solutions. Even if I apply it to a solution, close VS, reopen, and start working again, it will have reverted.

Does this happen to everyone else, or is this unique to me? Is there some global setting that forces this feature to stay off always? Do I have a corrupted file somewhere that's causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is normal behavior and this setting behaves like what you described in the previous VS versions.

**However**, thanks to [those members who is reporting this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/intellisense-toggle-completion-mode-should-persist/712824) and Microsoft has fixed this behavior in the latest VS2019 version.

**Since** **VS2015** is not supported by **Microsoft** so far, so this behavior cannot be fixed on VS2015 and I suggest you could install the latest VS2019 Community and get what you want.

Once you click the **Toggle Completion Mode** under **Edit**-->**Intellisense**, no matter you close VS, create a new project or a solution, use other c# file editor, it will never revert back.

Comment: That's very sad to hear. Unfortunately I cannot upgrade past VS2015 at this time due to hardware and third party API restrictions. I guess I'll just have to live with this infuriating "feature". That's too bad, it makes VS2015 almost unusable.

Comment: Thank you for the response though. Now I know that I can look forward to the fix if I'm ever able to upgrade.

Comment: Sorry. bro, after I tested in the latest `VS16.8.4`, the behavior went back. Also, I found the Team has known this behavior. They fixed it under `16.3` version but did not re-add it on `16.8.4`. And see this feedback. They know that `16.1<=version<=16.4`, it stores the record of your changes. But `>=16.5` version,  when you restart VS, it will reset to the default. It is annoying.

Comment: And [I have reported it to the Team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/why-I-click-Toggle-Completion-Mode-under/1349607?space=8&scope=follow&sort=newest) and vote it. You can also vote it or add any comments to raise more attention from Microsoft. And I will follow it.